# How to consider aspect ratio of mobile devices with CSS media query?

Tags: css

I want to crop a gallery image in height if the device has a smaller aspect ratio. E.g. iPhone 6,7,8 vs. X.

There must be some error in my code as this should be possible:

```
/* gallery img should be croped on phones with small height (e.g. iphone 6,7,8, but not X) */
/*@media (max-height: 700px){*/
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9){
  #cl_gallery_main{
      max-height: 260px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  #cl_gallery_main img{
      margin-top: -15%;
  }
}
```

The max-height works, but on iPhone PLUS the aspect ratio is also 16/9 so I want also to take this phone into consideration.

How can I target only aspect ratios with a higher screen?

Comment: Did you try combining them like this `@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) and (min-height: YOUR HEIGHT HERE) {}` ?

Comment: No, I didn't. But should the aspect ratio not be enough? The iphone x has over 16/9 more like 20/9.

Comment: I guess yeah, anyway you can read up on [how to target different iPhones here](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am looking for something different. There are so many phones out there nowadays and I want to crop an image with CSS if the device aspect ratio is smaller then x, because in that case the primary button is below the scroll which I would like to avoid.